# ember.js and rails layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm integrating ember to my rails application. So the problem I've found is - ember compile template and then append it to the body.

rails template:

```
 %body
#main-content
  = render 'layouts/header'
  .container.main
    #content
      = yield :dashboard

      #EMBER template
      %script{type:'text/x-handlebars'}
       {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="newEnrtyName"}}
       {{newEnrtyName}}

    - if has_left_menu?
      #navigation.l= render 'layouts/left-menu'
  = render 'layouts/footer'
```

Template append after footer :(

So is it possible tell ember work with only the part of page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the [`rootElement` property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement) on the application, eg.:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#ember-app-container'
});
```

You have to have this element existing in your HTML template.